# Instantiate one of two similar Python classes with an alias

Tags: python, class

For a machine-learning project I have a data module (based on lightning's `LightningDataModule`) that simplified looks somewhat like this:

```py
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import random_split

class DataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, in_memory: bool, year: int, test_year: int):
        self.in_memory = in_memory
        self.year = year
        self.test_year = test_year
        
    def setup(self, stage: str):
        if self.in_memory:
            from datasets import InMemoryDataSet as DataSet
        else:
            from datasets import IterativeDataSet as DataSet
            
        if stage == "fit":
            dataset_full = DataSet(year=self.year)
            self.dataset_train, self.dataset_val = random_split(dataset_full, 
                                                                [0.8, 0.2])
            
        if stage == "test":
            self.dataset_test = DataSet(year=self.test_year)
```

In a different file I defined two types of datasets, one where all the data is loaded into RAM and another where the data is loaded bit by bit.

Now, to collect all data related processes into one module, I'd like to put the content of  `datasets.py` in the same file as the class `DataModule`.

However, I can't find any "elegant" way to accomplish this and I would like to avoid repeated if-else statements, especially when the `setup`-method grows more complex. For example this

```py
def setup(self, stage: str):
        if stage == "fit":
            if self.in_memory:
                dataset_full = InMemoryDataSet(year=self.year)
            else:
                dataset_full = IterativeDataSet(year=self.year)
            self.dataset_train, self.dataset_val = random_split(dataset_full,
                                                                [0.8, 0.2])
            
        if stage == "test":
            if self.in_memory:
                self.dataset_test = InMemoryDataSet(year=self.test_year)
            else:
                self.dataset_test = IterativeDataSet(year=self.test_year)
```

looks like a maintenance nightmare, especially if arguments are added/removed/edited, or if additional stages are implemented.

So is there a better way to have the datasets in the same module (maybe by renaming them with an alias?) without resorting to nested if-else clauses?

Comment: Having a `setup` method that has to be called separately from `__init__` seems like a possible anti-pattern. I also wonder what `stage == "test"` actually means in practice... maybe you are better not having separate vars for `year` and `test_year` but instead pass the test value as `year` when in the test stage. Hard to know without more context, but this question has the feeling of trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Is there something else that you are likely to want to add into `setup()`? At the moment it looks like two booleans control the creation of an instance you assign to `self.dataset`.

Comment: I see you've edited the question. Now your `setup()` method looks like it is initialising two different classes. Do you need two separate classes?

Comment: @Anentropic This `setup` method framework comes from lightning's `LightningDataModule` class that I'm using. `setup` is used to determine which dataset should be loaded depending on if I want to test/predict/train my model. Not 100% sure, but I think in that case it's pertinent to have separate vars for `year` and `test_year`. Here's the [link](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/data/datamodule.html) to the docs, with an example on which my code is based.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, I tried to make the question clearer and to give a bit more context! Not sure I understand your question correctly, but in the first code snippet I always initialize only one dataset at the time. Depending on whether I'm training or testing my model. And since in the training case I further split the dataset in two it's useful to have a self.dataset_train and self.dataset_test instance, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most Pythonic solution, but you can opt for a dictionary and ternary to reduce the repeated code:

```py
def setup(self, stage: str):
    yearDict = {
      "fit": self.year,
      "test": self.test_year
    }
    dataset = InMemoryDataSet if self.in_memory else IterativeDataSet
    
    self.dataset = dataset(year=yearDict[stage])
```

I assume the types of dataset won't be expanded too much, but it can always be replaced with a dictionary.

Comment: The dictionary is definitely a nice idea! Even though I won't use it in my case your example gave me exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that it was possible to do something like: `dataset = InMemoryDataSet` and initialize the dataset in a later call!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the inputs! In the end [B Remmelzwaal`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76770779/17396813) led me to exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that I can assign a class to a variable without initializing it, which I guess is the first thing that I should have tried. So in my example the new code would be:

```py
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import random_split

class DataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, in_memory: bool, year: int, test_year: int):
        self.in_memory = in_memory
        self.year = year
        self.test_year = test_year
        
    def setup(self, stage: str):
        # Those are the lines that changed
        if self.in_memory:
            DataSet = InMemoryDataSet
        else:
            DataSet = IterativeDataSet
            
        if stage == "fit":
            dataset_full = DataSet(year=self.year)
            self.dataset_train, self.dataset_val = random_split(dataset_full, 
                                                                [0.8, 0.2])
            
        if stage == "test":
            self.dataset_test = DataSet(year=self.test_year)
            

class InMemoryDataSet():
    pass


class IterativeDataSet():
    pass
```

If there's any hidden dangers in assigning (and practically renaming) classes like this, I'd appreciate any comments on that :)

Comment: no hidden dangers, I'd be inclined to rename `Dataset` var to `dataset_cls` though